# Differentiating staging and production admin pages by colour in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I often have the admin pages for my staging sites and my production site open simultaneously. There's a big risk I'll inadvertently take an action on the wrong site so I manually edit the admin css files for each to make the toolbar a different colour in each. That way I can see instantly which site I'm on.

I was wondering whether there's a way of injecting a class (or something similar) from the htaccess file for each site. This is something fixed for each site so wouldn't need me to edit the css file each time I make a change that affects it.

Answer (score 1):

You could include an empty css file in your admin theme, then put it on gitignore and fill in your desired deviation on the staging system. Just make sure you override the default css that is not on gitignore.